# Close dialog component from effect

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I need to close angular material dialog from @ngrx/effect

here is my code

```
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { AddComponent } from "./../../add/add.component";

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
@Effect()
addNewUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.UserActionTypes.addNewUser),
         mergeMap((user: actions.addNewUser) =>
             this.userService.createUser(user.user).pipe(
                map(() => {
                  new actions.LoadUsers(),
                  this.notificationService.success("User added successfully!");
                  this.dialogRef.close();     <------ // here i try to close
                }),
              catchError(error => of(new actions.Error(error.error)))
            )
        )
    );

constructor(
    private actions$: Actions<actions.UserActions>,
    private userService: UserService,
    private notificationService: NotificationPopUpServiceService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddComponent>
) {}
}
```

And with this i get error

> main.ts:13 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[EffectsRootModule -> InjectionToken ngrx/effects: Root Effects -> UserEffects -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

What is the best way to close material-dialog from effect or from service? Because we always need to set a name for the dialog component?

Thank you

Comment: You need to send another action in Effect and subscribe to that action in your dialog

Comment: @jsbin thank you, pls, do you have any example?

Comment: You haven't the right import in your module

Comment: @Wandrille If you mean on MatDialogRef, i import it from `import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";`

Comment: Have you specified an appropropirate provider in your @NgModule (e.g. app.module.ts)?  ALSO: look here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/

Comment: @paulsm4 yes... everything of this working if i directly close from the same component without ngrx-effect, but if I try to close from another component/service, this not working

Comment: I dont have any examples. Or you can pass reference of the dialog in action payload and call `close()` on it. In your current code you are not even calling `close()` on the instance of your opened diaog

Comment: @jsbin how you mean I'm not calling? In the constructor I defined `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddComponent>`, and this `AddComponent is my dialog component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find a solution, but If there something better pls, let me know...
I add `this.dialogRef.closeAll()`

```
class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private dialogRef: MatDialog,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
  ) {}

  @Effect()
      addNewUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(actions.UserActionTypes.addNewUser),
          mergeMap((user: actions.addNewUser) =>
            this.userService.createUser(user.user).pipe(
              map(() => {
                new actions.LoadUsers(),
                this.notificationService.success("User added successfully!");
                this.dialogRef.closeAll();    <--- //this is the key
              }),
      catchError(error => of(new actions.Error(error.error)))
    )
  ));
}
```

EDIT:

modal is closed, but I get error

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Effect "UserEffects.addNewUser$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined
>
> TypeError: Actions must be objects

Any help? Thnx

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution to closing dialog is subscribing to the effect variable 
ie

```
// close the dialog
// Inside the dialog component
 this.userEffects.addNewUser$.pipe(
     ofType(Actions.LoadUsers)
 ).subscribe(_ => this.matDialogRef.close());
```

Comment: Be careful when using this solution! It will help for closing the dialog, but could create another bug. If you use `EffectsModule.forRoot()` in your app.module, then it will automatically subscribe to your effects for you. By creating a second subscription to an effect like in this solution, everything in that effect will be triggered twice (for example http requests).

Answer (score 1):

regarding your 'dispatched an invalid action: undefined'

every effect must dispatch an action, unless you specify:
{ dispatch: false }

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to `actions$: Actions` in your dialog component, subscribe to it and close the dialog when the action is triggered, without recurring to NgRx effects and needing to inject all the dialogs references.

Your dialog component's constructor would include, among other things:

```js
constructor(    
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialogComponent>,
    private readonly actions$: Actions) {}
```

In `ngOnInit` you'd listen to the relevant action meant to close the dialog. I generally rely on `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe from observables.

```js
private readonly subscription = new Subscription();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.actions$
        .pipe(ofType(actions.UserActionTypes.LoadUsers))
        .subscribe(() => this.dialogRef.close())
    );
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Pay attention to the action you're listening to; it must be one triggered by the `addNewUser$` effect, which seems to be `new actions.LoadUsers()` in your case. The common pattern is to follow an `addNewUser` action with an `addNewUserSuccess` or `addNewUserFailure`.

You may have several error dialogs popping up at the same time. This approach allows one to manage concurrent dialogs made of different components: `closeAll()` will (unsurprisingly) close all the material dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your `@Effect`, you need to provide the dependency:

```
 private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponentToClose>
```

And you need to import `MatDialogModule` inside your module where your effect is.